# How to move a layer in QGIS Toc above an existing group?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, table-of-contents

If in QGIS TOC a group already exists and I add a new layer via

```
QgsVectorLayer* lyr= mQGisIface->addVectorLayer(uri->uri(),Title, myProviderName);
```

the new layer will be inserted within the group. How can I move it outside/above the group?

Comment: didn't tested it until yet, the problem is buried on my desk...

Answer (score 3):

You can do that by following these steps (QGIS >= v.2.4):

1. Get the layer tree object

   ```
   root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
   ```
2. Find the desired group by name

   ```
   mygroup = root.findGroup("group1")
   ```
3. Get the group index

   ```
   parentGroup = mygroup.parent()
   groupIndex=-1
   for child in parentGroup.children():
        groupIndex+=1
        if mygroup == child:
            break
   ```
4. Create the new layer object

   ```
   mylayer = QgsVectorLayer("/PathToYour/data.shp", "my layer", "ogr")
   ```
5. Add the layer to the QGIS Map Layer Registry

   ```
   QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(mylayer, False)
   ```
6. Insert the layer above the group

   ```
   parentGroup.insertChildNode(groupIndex, QgsLayerTreeLayer(mylayer))
   ```