# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'setName' (or insertChildNode)

Tags: pyqgis, attributeerror

I am trying to make group and fill it with layers in pyQGIS.

Piece of my code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtCore import QFileInfo

from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import iface 

group = iface.legendInterface().addGroup( 'abc')
group.setName("Group X")
```

But I got only error AttributeError: `'int' object has no attribute 'setName'`

May I import some other class or where is problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to avoid the `legendInterface` and use instead `Layer Tree` classes directly.

You're getting that error because `addGroup` returns an index (`integer`), that you're storing in your `group` variable and then calling a method that integers don't support.

You can see how to add groups (and even subgroups) to QGIS Layer Tree here: [How to add a layer group using pyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66169/how-to-add-a-layer-group-using-pyqgis/134377#134377)

Once you've added a group, you can add layers to it by calling `addLayer()`:

```
myGroup.addLayer(myLayer)
```

Have a look at these related posts:

- [How to add layer/raster with specific position in the QGIS layer list?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62053/how-to-add-layer-raster-with-specific-position-in-the-qgis-layer-list/127085#127085)
- [How to load a raster layer at the top of the QGIS ToC?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86892/how-to-load-a-raster-layer-at-the-top-of-the-qgis-toc/131684#131684)
- [How to move a layer in QGIS Toc above an existing group?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/108316/how-to-move-a-layer-in-qgis-toc-above-an-existing-group/127101#127101)